# Retrieve records from mysql that satisfies for all values in IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I have a query:
SELECT
ZIPSECvc255Zip,ZIPSECCODIServiceType
FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary
WHERE   ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055
AND ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302
    AND ZIPSECCODIServiceType in (263,1012)
    AND ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105

I am getting follow result:
ZIPSECvc255Zip  ZIPSECCODIServiceType
  17001               263
  17003               1012
  17007               1012
  17003               263
```

I want only a single record of 17003 because it is related with both ZIPSECCODIServiceType(ie. 263,1012). How can I achieve that using query?

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
SELECT ZIPSECvc255Zip FROM  
(SELECT ZIPSECvc255Zip, count(*) AS cnt
   FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary
  WHERE   ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055
    AND ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302
    AND ZIPSECCODIServiceType in (263,1012)
    AND ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105
  GROUP BY ZIPSECvc255Zip)
WHERE CNT = 2
```

You will want to substitute number 2 with as many corrispondences you want, should they change (ie how many number you have in your IN condition).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ZIPSECvc255Zip,ZIPSECCODIServiceType
FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary
WHERE   ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055
AND ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302
AND ZIPSECCODIServiceType = 263 and 
ZIPSECvc255Zip in
   (
     select ZIPSECvc255Zip FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary
      WHERE   ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055
      AND ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302
       AND ZIPSECCODIServiceType = 1012
       AND ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105
   )
AND ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
SELECT
ZIPSECvc255Zip,ZIPSECCODIServiceType
FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary
WHERE  rowid = (SELECT max(rowid) FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary WHERE ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055 AND ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302 
AND ZIPSECCODIServiceType in (263,1012)
AND ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105 GROUP BY count(ZIPSECvc255Zip)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t1.ZIPSECvc255Zip,t1.ZIPSECCODIServiceType
FROM towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary as t1 INNER JOIN towSearch_ZIP_ZipCodesSecondary as t2
ON (t1.ZIPSECvc255Zip = t2.ZIPSECvc255Zip AND t1.ZIPSECCODIServiceType = '263' AND t2.ZIPSECCODIServiceType = '1012')
WHERE   
t1.ZIPSECCOMlAPAssignee = 57055
AND 
t1.ZIPSECCODlAPStatus = 302
AND 
t1.ZIPSECADDIKey = 314105
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325ba/9